# How to position app bootstrap logic in a React/Redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When a web app is loaded I want a WebSocket connection to be established with the server.

So this is an asynchronous bootstrap activity.

Would it be idiomatic to create a higher order component that uses conditional rendering of the wrapped component (the app!) to "block" until a WebSocket connection is established?

```
// containers/App/index.js
export default withWebSocketConnection(app)


// components/WebSocketConnection/index.js
function withWebSocketConnection(wrappedComponent) {
  class AppWithWebSocketConnection extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      // set this.props.isConnecting to be true
      websocket.connect().then(() => {
        // set this.props.isConnecting to be false
      });
    }

    render() {
      return this.props.isConnecting ? <div>Connecting...</div> : <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
    }
  }
  return AppWithWebSocketConnection;
}

export default withWebSocketConnection;
```

Comment: First, you can't (and/or shouldn't) set "this.props". Second, do all websocket/api/asynchronous call in your componentDidMount.

Comment: What I usually do is, set a `state` property (flag) for the connection state: `constructor(props){super(props);this.state={connected: false};}`. As @Nevosis said, use `componentDidMount` to establish the connection and, on success, set the state accordingly: `this.setState({connected: true})`. If the wrapped component does not make sense in a context without a WebSocket connection, then it does make sense to **not** render the component (which you're basically doing in your example).

Comment: If your wrapped component can/should work without an established connection, then best option would be to render it and set the connection as a prop. After connecting, set the connection and rerender the component. Judging from your example, I'd say that your `WrappedComponent` does not care much about WebSocket and that my first suggestion would be better in this case.

Comment: Thank you both, Why is `componentWillMount` less correct than (or wrong) `componentDidMount` for initiating the attempt at establishing a WebSocket connection?

Comment: It's recommended in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) because it's often the case that after getting some data, you'll want to rerender your component (e.g. populate a table with async data). This means calling `setState()` and, if you call `setState()` inside `componentWillMount` it will be ignored. This, of course, means that the async method is quicker than the rest of `componentWillMount` :)

Comment: Thank you. I agree that blocking on connection establishment is not necessary. So would you encapsulate the triggering of the logic for establishing the connection inside a dedicated component (eg. `WebSocketConnection`) that renders nothing, but simply emits an action (eg. `CONNECT_WEBSOCKET`), triggering a saga?

Comment: You can, but its more an architecture case than development. I only do react actions  in my api layer (but it's not a component, just a JS plain object with functions). Do you use redux ? (as you're talking about emitting an action) If yes, just dispatch it when your connexion is successful, and render your component if this.props.isConnecting is true. (it's basically the same WITHOUT redux, but you have to pass a callback to your connexion layer)